# Angular js grid with select all checkbox to delete records

Tags: c#, angularjs

I following this article to get the selectall check box for grid and delete the selected rows at once.

[Website which i am referring](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-ui-grid-sorting-filtering-paging-grouping)

Now i  need to implement where user can delete all the selected records at once.. how  can i get the selected from records ? i have an api where i need to pass the parameter of the selected records ..

i am sharing the image which can make you understand  any help on this would be great ![image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X5g8.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>

Angularjs UI-Grid Example

</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module("uigridApp", ["ui.grid"]);

app.controller("uigridCtrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.users = [

{ name: "Madhav Sai", age: 10, location: 'Nagpur' },

{ name: "Suresh Dasari", age: 30, location: 'Chennai' },

{ name: "Rohini Alavala", age: 29, location: 'Chennai' },

{ name: "Praveen Kumar", age: 25, location: 'Bangalore' },

{ name: "Sateesh Chandra", age: 27, location: 'Vizag' }

];

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">

.myGrid {

width: 500px;

height: 200px;

}

</style>

</head>

<body ng-app="uigridApp">

<h2>AngularJS UI Grid Example</h2>

<div ng-controller="uigridCtrl">

<div ui-grid="{ data: users }" class="myGrid"></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the screenshots you have provided don't show any information about what the code you have written does, and it would be very difficult to provide any code in an answer.

Comment: Code is added  now

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any code for the checkbox in this example?  or even the presence of a delete button?